# Arch Linux AMD and NVIDIA Gpus

Tags: linux, drivers, arch-linux, dual-gpu

I have 2 gpus: AMD RX 6500XT and a Nvidia 3060.
I would like to use the 6500XT for the System (I'm using Arch Linux) and the Nvidia for training some Deep Learning Models.
I have both gpus installed in my computer and the 6500XT is plugged via HDMI to the monitor.
I'm running a fresh Arch Linux install (using archinstall with i3wm and linux kernel) and it works nicely. After rebooting i have a black screen with flashing cursor and nothing appends.
I tried to blacklist nouveau driver but it didn't fix the problem.

Someone can help ?